# Understanding unlift and unapply in Scala play framework

Tags: scala, play-json

In ["Play for Scala book"](https://www.manning.com/books/play-for-scala) Listing 8.12

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
implicit val productWrites: Writes[Product] = (
  (JsPath \ "ean").write[Long] and
  (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
  (JsPath \ "description").write[String]
)(unlift(Product.unapply))
```

They explain unlift and unapply as follow:

> Finally, our formatter in listing 8.12 uses the and operator to
>   combine the formatters, and unlift to change the unapply function’s
>   return type to what’s required here. The details of the API for
>   combining formatters like this and the reason why **unlift is required**
>   **are more complicated**, but you can safely ignore that for now.

So what does this unlift do and how it works ?

I tried this [link](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/unlifting.html) but both are not the same unlift

Answer (score 0):

Play JSON `unlift` now "just" [call Scala `Function.unlift`](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/master/play-functional/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/functional/syntax/package.scala#L34), which [itself](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/Function$.html#unlift[T,R](f:T=%3EOption[R]):PartialFunction[T,R]) "convert" a `T => Option[R]` to the corresponding partial function, required by Play JSON.

As a `unapply` for a case class is expected to have a signature like `(PropA, PropB, PropC) => Option[MyCaseClass]`, passing it to `unlift` create the corresponding partial function.